# jQuery - Traversing through list elements to get nested elements and attributes

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have posted the following generated html where I need to select specific elements from.
For example I need to access and get the values of href in all cases as well as src and alt attributes of img element.

```
<ul id="query" class="clicked inline">
   <li>
     <a class="filterterm" href="#">×</a>
     <span class="term">design</span>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="filterterm" href="http://www.askgraphics.com/">×</a>
     <span class="bingresult">Website design, Blog design and Web..</span>
     </li>
   <li>
     <a class="filterterm" href="http://www.askgraphics.com">
       <img class="imgresult" width="60px" border="1px" height="60px"    src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7423/13129389874_a07ced37ee_t.jpg" alt="Image">
     </a>
     <span class="imageterm"></span>
   </li>
```

I've tried with a code like the following but no success

```
 ('ul#query > li > .term').each(function(i,data){
        console.log(" Term Data"+data.text());            
      });

    });
    $('ul#query > li > img > .imgresult').each(function(i,data){
        console.log(" Image Data"+data);
      });

    });
    $('ul#query > li > .linkresult').each(function(i,data){
        console.log(" Link Data"+data.text());           
        });

    });
    $('ul#query > li > img > .videoresult').each(function(i,data){
        console.log(" Video Data"+data);           

    });
```

Comment: And what output do you expect, or want, from that html?

Comment: This is the generated html as I see it from  Firebug from where I need to access/get the value of href for each case and the pair {href, src} for the last li using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1) Lots of syntax errors in your javascript, and missing closing `ul` tag in your HTML. Next time, consider posting a fiddle along with your code sample, and cleaning up your code before posting. It'll help you troubleshoot the problem, and make it easier for the folks on SO to help you.

2) jQuery's `each()` method passes an HTML element, not a jQuery wrapped set, to the function handler. That means constructs like `data.text()` don't work. You can either convert to a jQuery wrapped set:

```
console.log(" Term Data" + $(data).text());
```

or, preferably, use the `innerText` or `textContent` property of the element itself:

```
console.log(" Term Data" + data.textContent);
```

3) Your selectors are needlessly specific, and incorrect to boot. In general, use the least-specific selectors necessary to get you just the data you want.

New sample code (also [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/XFUNG/))

```
$('.term').each(function (i, termEl) {
    console.log(" Term Data: ", termEl.textContent);
});

$('.imgresult').each(function (i, imgEl) {
    console.log(" Image Data: ", imgEl.src);
});

$('.linkresult').each(function (i, aEl) {
    console.log(" Link Data: ", aEl.textContent, aEl.href);
});

$('.videoresult').each(function (i, videoEl) {
    console.log(" Video Data: ", videoEl.href);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately my jQuery includes many errors because I have just started studying and using it. The above code partially works. I can get termEl.textContent and img.src except from the videoEl.href, imgEl.href or aEl.href. I was thinking of accessing with the same way defining a class for each <a> but I need to to get url and src (for images) or url and title (for links) as pairs. How can I ensure this? Thank you again for your time.